# Bounce effect with changing height on list items js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, bounce

I am trying to crack this task: I need to make list items to bounce 2 times on button click. But they need to bounce the second time with 40% of the first time bounce distance.
I was only able to implement simple bounce on list elements, but I could not find how to implement a change of bounce distance.
Could you help me with that?
I would be very grateful for your advice!

Code snippet:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
    <title>Bounce Effect</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        ul li{
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        li {
            float:left;
            margin-right:10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Bounce Effect!</h2>
    <button id="button" onclick="bounceEffect()">Click me!</button>
    <h2 id="header">Bouncer!</h2>
    <div id="list">
        <ul>
            <li id="a"><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li id="b"><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li id="c"><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li id="d"><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li id="e"><a href="#">5</a></li>
            <li id="f"><a href="#">6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>      
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function bounceEffect(){
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('button').click(function () {
                    $('li a').effect("bounce", {times: 2}, 300);
                })
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem. I just used **distance** parameter and changed it dynamically with the help of external variable in **bounceEffect** function. It is a bit slow, but the code works just fine.
Hope, it`ss gonna help someone!

```
function bounceEffect() {
            var distance = 60;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('button').click(function () {
                    $('li a').effect("bounce", {times: 2, distance: distance*=0.4}, 200);   
                })
            });
        }
```